# Global Javascript timer not resetting from button click

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, model-view-controller, timer

I'm working in an MVC app and I'm having an issue with a global javascript timer  that will send the user to the login page if their session expires.  Setting the timer and having it execute the logoff function works fine, but I've tried to set that a click function should reset the timer (to try and prevent the timer from closing a user's session prematurely) I'm not sure what I've done incorrectly.

Code in _Layout.csthml

```
<script>
//session end
var sessionTimer = 0;
var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout- 1;
var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;

function SessionEnd() {
    document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit();
}
function SetTimer() {
    ClearTimer();
    sessionTimer = setInterval('SessionEnd()', sTimeout);
};
function ClearTimer() {
    clearInterval(sessionTimer);
};
$('body').on('click', function () {
        ClearTimer();
});
$(document).ready(function () {
    SetTimer();
});
```

Relevant Code in Web.config:

```
<sessionState timeout="2"></sessionState>
```

EDIT:  I realize right now it shows that I'm just clearing the timer on button click.  I just wanted to see if it would actually clear it before I try resetting it each time.

Comment: well you clear it, but you do not restart it...

Comment: Yeah, I was testing first that it would even clear the timer, which it isn't doing.  That's the main problem; for some reason the timer doesn't clear on the button click.

Comment: well you are calling it on body click,.... is the click event getting to the body? Is the button preventing the click from reaching it?

Comment: The event is getting triggered on every click, as expected.  It just doesn't actually clear the timer.  So, every time, after one minute, the logoff method gets called.

Comment: Well you should not be using setInterval() you should be using setTimeout(). If you say that `ClearTimer` is being called than I would suspect you have more than one timer being triggered somehow.

Comment: Also Is that the exact code you are using/testing?

Comment: Yes, exact code.  I did try changing it to setTimeout/clearTimeout with the same results.  And after stepping through the code a few times, I do see that sessionTimer = 0 is getting called more than once, which is probably why ClearTimer doesn't work.  But I'm not sure why that's getting called more than once.

I did also try changing the code to remove calling SetTimer on document.ready, and just running it under "var sTimeout = parseInt..." which didn't make a difference.

Comment: The code as written should work. So issue is how the code is injected into the page. Sounds like you have it added more than once...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was having this in _Layout and using $('document').ready for triggering the SetTimer.  Code is in _Index_Layout and is as follows:

```
    <script>
//session end
    if (sessionTimer === undefined)
        var sessionTimer = 0;
    var sessionTimeoutWarning = @Session.Timeout- 1;
    var sTimeout = parseInt(sessionTimeoutWarning) * 60 * 1000;
    SetTimer();

    function SessionEnd() {
        document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit();
    }
    function SetTimer() {
        ClearTimer();
        sessionTimer = setTimeout('SessionEnd()', sTimeout);
    };
    function ClearTimer() {
        clearTimeout(sessionTimer);
    };
    $('body').on('click', function () {
            ClearTimer();
    });
</script>
```